# Performance of wc -l

Tags: linux, bash, awk, time, wc

I ran the following command :

```
time for i in {1..100}; do find / -name "*.service" | wc -l; done
```

got a 100 lines of the result then :

**real  0m35.466s
user    0m15.688s
sys     0m14.552s**

I then ran the following command :

```
time for i in {1..100}; do find / -name "*.service" | awk 'END{print NR}'; done
```

got a 100 lines of the result then :

**real  0m35.036s
user    0m15.848s
sys     0m14.056s**

I precise I already ran `find / -name "*.service"` just before so it was cached for both commands.

I expected `wc -l` to be faster. Why is it not ?

Comment: The initial `find` was caching direntries (inodes), not contents.

Comment: The result of `find` isn't going to be cached.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, ...well, it is *slightly* -- the dentry cache will at least mean the filesystem doesn't need to go back to underlying media. It's still a new `find` instance each time talking to the filesystem each time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Sure, agree that the relevant part of the filesystem will be cached :)

Comment: @shrimpdrake, ...that said, even with stronger supporting benchmarks, I'm not sure that this is defensibly topical here. `wc` is by no means "unique to software development", as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- and since there aren't documented performance guarantees for either tool, and *also* doesn't exist a single canonical implementation, this isn't really a question for which a canonical answer exists.

Comment: @shrimpdrake, ...definitely, though, `find` is the biggest wildcard -- copy its output to a file (ideally on tmpfs) before trying something like this again. I'd also suggest looking through `strace` output for each -- if they're reading with different block sizes, that's liable to be the whole of your delta (should it still exist at all). Context switches between the kernel and userland are expensive.

Comment: (It might also be interesting to know if `LC_CTYPE=C`, turning off multi-byte character support, has any effect).

Comment: Since you're timing the whole loop, the bulk of the time is probably in the `find` and the difference between the `wc` and `awk` is more or less lost in the noise.

Comment: You are launching `find` 100 times.  Unless there are a lot of files found, you are basically benchmarking the filesystem, IO and process launch overhead much more than you are benchmarking `wc` or `awk`.  Even if there are a lot of files found, `find` has more work to do than `wc` or `awk` anyway.  `awk` and `wc` probably spend more time being started than counting lines.

Comment: How many lines is `find` producing for you to count?  @Fred is likely correct that `awk` and `wc` have minimal work to do.  Try counting the lines from a large file, instead.

Comment: thanks for those answers, find was effectively the wildcard here,
I put a big txt file of 14M lines in /media/virtuelram/ and executed both "time for i in {1..100}; do awk 'END{ print NR}' /media/virtuelram/rockyou.txt; done" and "time for i in {1..100}; do wc -l /media/virtuelram/rockyou.txt; done" and the results were quite the opposite : 13.027s for wc and 80.207s for awk !

Comment: It's not `find` that caused it to deviate. Try running any process 100 times and time each one in a loop and you will be surprised the output is different.  Say `for i in {1..100}; do time ls -l > /dev/null 2>&1; done`. CPU scheduling is what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. Such a small difference is usually not significant:

   ```
   0m35.466s - 0m35.036s = 0m0.43s  or 1.2%
   ```
2. Yet `wc -l` *is* faster (10x) than `awk 'END{print NR}'`.

   ```
   % time seq 100000000  | awk 'END{print NR}' > /dev/null

   real    0m13.624s
   user    0m14.656s
   sys 0m1.047s
   % time seq 100000000  | wc -l > /dev/null

   real    0m1.604s
   user    0m2.413s
   sys 0m0.623s
   ```
3. My guess is that the hard drive cache holds the `find` results, so after the first run with `wc -l`, most of the reads needed for `find` are in the cache.  Presumably the difference in times between the initial `find` with disk reads and the second `find` with cache reads, would be greater than the difference in run times between `awk` and `wc`.

   One way to test this is to reboot, which clears the hard disk cache, then run the two tests again, but *in the reverse order*, so that `awk` is run first.  I'd expect that the first-run `awk` would be even slower than the first-run `wc`, and the second-run `wc` would be faster than the second-run `awk`.

Comment: Almost as slow as `awk` is `sed`.  `time seq 100000000  | sed -n '$=' > /dev/null` comes in at *12s*.

Answer (score 2):

other's have mentioned that you're probably timing `find`, not `wc` or `awk`. still, there may be interesting differences to explore between `wc` and `awk` in their various flavors.

here are the results I get:

```
Mac OS 10.10.5 awk    0.16m lines/second
GNU awk/gawk 4.1.4    4.4m  lines/second
Mac OS 10.10.5 wc     6.8m  lines/second
GNU wc 8.27          11m    lines/second
```

i didn't use `find`, but instead used `wc -l` or `awk 'END{print NR}' on a large text file (66k lines) in a loop.

i varied the order of the commands and didn't find any deviations large enough to change the rankings i reported.

`LC_CTYPE=C` had no measurable effect on any of these.

conclusions

1. don't use mac builtin command line tools except for trivial amounts of data.
2. GNU wc is faster than GNU awk at counting lines.

i use MacPorts GNU binaries. it would be interesting to see how Homebrew binaries compare. (i'm guessing they'd lose.)